# Dapper inserting records when column type is incorrect

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have the following query that inserts a record into our MySQL Database.
`INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Type) VALUES('ASSD', 1)`
The column type for ID is BigInt
We are using Dapper for the Insert `ExecuteAsync(query, null);`
I would expect Dapper to throw an exception, but instead it inserts a row setting the Id column to zero. How can I get Dapper to throw an exception as the data being inserted is incorrect?

I would expect Dapper to throw an exception, but instead it inserts a row setting the Id column to zero.

Comment: Dapper doesn't know you database, it just acts as a middle-man and sends the SQL to the database. MySql should make sure that data is the right format and return an error. There must be some setting in MySQL that ensures that.

Answer (score 2):

This MySQL server behavior depends on current [SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) setting.

If you want the server to produce an error while trying to insert incorrect value then you must set global (edit my.ini and restart MySQL) or session (execute according SET statement in this connection before) SQL Mode to STRICT.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id BIGINT, Type INT)
```

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = ''  -- clear session mode
```

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Type) VALUES('ASSD', 1) 
-- accepted, warning produced, zero inserted
```

```
SHOW WARNINGS
```

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: 'ASSD' for column 'Id' at row 1 |

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'   -- set strict mode
```

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Type) VALUES('ASSD', 2)
-- ejected, error generated
```

> ```
> Incorrect integer value: 'ASSD' for column 'Id' at row 1
> ```

```
SHOW WARNINGS
```

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: 'ASSD' for column 'Id' at row 1 |

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DKv1pmJ2)